# Listen Gem compared to FSSM gem - which one is better?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

Just have read sass [changelog](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html) and found out that [FSSM](http://rubygems.org/gems/fssm) (the gem that had been used for compass watch task) had been replaced with [Listen](http://rubygems.org/gems/listen)

I've tried to google to find out the reasons but can not find exactly reasons.
As of today, number of total downloads of `FSSM` is way bigger than that one of `Listen`.
Besides, as far as I can understand (correct me if I wrong) FSSM gracefully degrades for polling if inotify-like events are not supported. An Listen does not.

So, can somebody explain what are the reasons to use the Listen gem instead of FSSM if I want to use file system events in my script?

**UPD:**
   Ha-ha, after updating FSSM and attempting to call it, I get the following message from FSSM:

> Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects,
>   FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will
>   be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please
>   let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b
>   - Travis Tilley

So it looks like the decision of FSSM creators. This, nevertheless, does not abolish my question - what has been wrong with FSSM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The switch was discussed in [this](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/491) Compass issue. [Listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) seems to be a bit more actively maintained by multiple core Guard developers than [FSSM](https://github.com/ttilley/fssm) at the moment. If the warning message is from @ttilley (who authored FSSM) that lends it further credence.

I got that FSSM warning message too when running `compass watch somefile.css.scss` (using compass 0.12.2).  It seems to be just a [coming attraction](http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/browse_thread/thread/ee9c445464bd653c) of the switch to Listen which does not seem to have happened [yet](http://compass-style.org/CHANGELOG/).

According to the current Listen docs, it too gracefully degrades to polling if the OS adapter has trouble figuring out if the the files changed.